# Changing dataframe format so rows become columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks as follows:

```
Category    Amount
Group       5
Country     10
People      100
Buildings   50
```

I want to change it to this format:

```
Group  Country  People  Buildings
5      10       100     50
```

reproducible dataframe code:

```
{'Category': {0: 'Group', 1: 'Country', 2: 'People', 3: 'Buidings'},
 Amount: {0: 5, 1: 10, 2: 100, 3: 50}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may work on `pandas.DataFrame.transpose()`

```
df_transposed = df.T # or df.transpose()
```

[image: An example]